# read a list of string from a json configuration file python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file containing the following lines:

```
{"param1": 1,
"param2": 250,
"param3": 250}
```

that I read in the init of my python class as follow:

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        variables = json.load(f)
    for key, value in variables.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

how should I modify my code and/or json file if I have to read a parameter that is a list of string?
My json file should be something like this:

```
{"param1": 1,
"param2": 250,
"param3": 250,
"param4": [true,false,false,true]} <- I am quite sure that this is wrong! :)
```

Comment: it's not what you want, but it returns a valid list of booleans, so it works. if you want strings, just add double quotes.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add some code to your `__init__` to convert these booleans into strings, but [Jean-François Fabre's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) solution is definitely the simpler one.